# How can I plot my evaluation loss with estimators in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

Hi I want to plot the evaluation loss like the training loss like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcaPL.png)
, not just a dot like tensorflow tutorials, how I do that, this is my code, with this code I get only a dot for evaluation loss:

```
accuracy=tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])
    metrics = {"accuracy": accuracy}
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy[1])

    #Configure of the training operation
    if mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op=optimizer.minimize(loss=loss,global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,loss=loss,train_op=train_op)


    #Configure the evaluation operation
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)
```

When I put "loss":loss in metrics I get an error, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type of loss you want to use :

Look at the documentation : https://keras.io/losses/

For example : `loss='mean_squared_error'`